# Must a function hold true for all (x,y) to be harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I've found lots of examples that show various functions that are harmonic but I still can't figure something out.  Does a function have to hold true for all (x,y) to be considered harmonic or is it enough for it to hold along a certain line or at a certain point?

For example, I'm currently working with the function `v(x,y) = x^3 + y^3` which, when you solve for the double derivatives of x and y and place it into the Laplace equation yields `6x + 6y = 0`.  Now, this is true along the line `y=-x`.

Is that enough to show that the function is harmonic or does the Laplace equation have to hold true for all (x,y) and not just along a single line?

Comment: It is weird to call a function harmonic when the Laplace equation is not satisfied everywhere.

Comment: it's also weird to say that a function holds true.

Comment: The function satisfies the Laplace equation along that line. However to be called harmonic at a point it must hold the equation in a neighborhood of that point. It is the same distinction as *complex differentiable* and *analytic*. Harmonic and analytic, like any concept, are created because they are hypothesis of certain theorems. In those theorems one needs the property in an open set. That is why that requirement is added to the concept.

Comment: I think generally one would say that a function is harmonic if it solves Laplace's equation on an open set.